# How to properly abort a thread with the use of a condition_variable?

Tags: c++, multithreading, concurrency, thread-safety, c++14

I have a class with some methods that should be thread safe, i.e. multiple threads should be able operate on the class object state. One of the methods spawns **a new thread that, every 10 seconds, updates a field**. Because this thread can be long-running, I'd like to be able to abort it properly.

I have implemented a solution that uses `std::condition_variable.wait_for()` to wait for an abortion signal inside the thread, but am not particularly sure if my solution is either optimal or correct at all.

```
class A
{
    unsigned int value; // A value that will be updated every 10 s in another thread
    bool is_being_updated; // true while value is being updated in another thread

    std::thread t;
    bool aborted; // true = thread should abort

    mutable std::mutex m1;
    mutable std::mutex m2;
    std::condition_variable cv;

  public:
    A();
    ~A();

    void begin_update(); // Creates a thread that periodically updates value
    void abort(); // Aborts the updating thread

    unsigned int get_value() const;
    void set_value(unsigned int);   
};
```

This is how I implemented the methods:

```
A::A() : value(0), is_being_updated(false), aborted(false) { }

A::~A()
{
    // Not sure if this is thread safe?
    if(t.joinable()) t.join();
}

// Updates this->value every 10 seconds
void A::begin_update() 
{
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lck(m1);

    if (is_being_updated) return; // Don't allow begin_update() while updating          
    is_being_updated = true;  
    if (aborted) aborted = false;

    // Create a thread that will update value periodically
    t = std::thread([this] {             
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> update_lock(m2);              

        for(int i=0; i < 10; i++)
        {                        
            cv.wait_for(update_lock, std::chrono::seconds(10), [this]{ return aborted; });

            if (!aborted)
            {
                std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lck(m1);
                this->value++; // Update value
            }
            else
            {
                break; // Break on thread abort
            }       
        }

        // Locking here would cause indefinite blocking ...
        // std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lck(m1);
        if(is_being_updated) is_being_updated = false;                            
    }); 
}

// Aborts the thread created in begin_update()
void A::abort()
{
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lck(m1);        
    is_being_updated = false;
    this->value = 0; // Reset value         
    {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> update_lock(m2);        
        aborted = true;
    }       
    cv.notify_one(); // Signal abort ... 
    if(t.joinable()) t.join(); // Wait for the thread to finish            
}

unsigned int A::get_value() const
{
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lck(m1);
    return this->value;
}

void A::set_value(unsigned int v)
{
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lck(m1);        
    if (is_being_updated) return; // Cannot set value while thread is updating it       
    this->value = v;
}
```

This *seems* to work fine, but I'm uncertain about it being correct. My concerns are the following:

1. Is my destructor safe? Suppose that the updating thread has not been aborted and is still doing its job while `A` object goes out of scope. A switch to a different thread now happens while dtor's `t.join()` still hasn't finished, and the switched-to thread calls `begin_update()` on the same object. Is something like this possible? Should I introduce e.g. an extra `is_being_destructed` flag that I would set to true inside a destructor and that all other methods should check for being false before they can proceed? Or can no such undesired scenario happen?
2. Inside the thread, at the end, I'm setting `is_being_updated = false` without a lock, despite the variable being shared state. This can mean that other threads won't see its correct value, e.g. even after the thread is done, some other thread may still see the value as `is_being_updated == true` instead of `false`. I cannot lock the mutex, however, because `abort()` may have already locked it, meaning that the call will block indefinitely. I'm not sure about the best way to solve this, other than perhaps making `is_being_updated` atomic. Would that work?
3. I've read about spurious wakeups, but am not sure I the code should do anything extra to handle them. As far as I understand, the answer is *no*, and no problems are to be expected in this regard.

Is my thinking here correct? Did I miss anything else that I should have in mind?

Comment: The lambda in the wait_for is what handles the possible spurious wakeups.

Comment: You have a deadlock. The thread tries to acquire `m1` when it already holds `m2`. The `abort`ion function tries to acuire `m2` when it already holds `m1`.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz thanks, I don't know how I missed that. Making `value` atomic should fix this as the lock is no longer needed, I think ...

Comment: @w128 Except the logic of a condition variable requires that the lock protect the predicate. Otherwise, you have a race condition you can never fix -- both the predicate change and the condition variable signal can occur after you checked the predicate but before you blocked on the condition variable.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz yes indeed, in this case there's `update_lock` protecting the predicate; the `value` being updated need not be protected by a lock and can simply be atomic, unless my concurrency-obtuse mind is missing something else again ...

Comment: @w128 What if you check the atomic value and decide to block on the condition variable, but after you checked the value and before you blocked, another thread both changed the value and signaled the condition variable? You'd be blocked on the condition variable waiting for a signal that you already missed. The lock associated with the condition variable must protect the predicate.

Comment: @w128 The whole point of a condition variable is to give you an "unlock and wait" atomic operation so that you can block on the condition variable if and only if the thing you're waiting for hasn't occurred yet. If the lock doesn't protect the predicate (and it's atomic instead) then you don't have an atomic "unlock and wait" anymore (because the predicat4 isn't locked), and the condition variable ceases to guarantee that you don't wait for something that's already happened.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz forgive me if I'm misunderstanding this, but in the code, the lock protecting the predicate and granting "unlock and wait" is `std::unique_lock<std::mutex> update_lock(m2)`, and the value that would be problematic had it been atomic is `aborted` (the predicate). However, I'm talking about making `this->value` atomic, so that it can be updated in the if block without additional lock causing a potential deadlock. I believe that what you're talking about are issues that would arise if `aborted` were made atomic. Am I misreading this?

Comment: Oh, I got you. That's fine then.

Answer (score 1):

This stuff is always hard to check, so don't be afraid to question me if you think I misunderstand.

1. Short answer, no, it's not thread safe.

As long as the thread that has scope of `A` is the one calling abort (and doesn't forget to call abort), you won't experience a race condition, as `A::abort()` will block until the thread is joined. Under these assumptions, the `join` in your destructor is pointless.

If abort is called by the a thread that doesn't own `A`, then it's definitely possible for the thread to be `join`-ed twice, which is bad. Using `.joinable()` to decide to join a thread or not is a big red flag.

Please remove one of your `if(t.joinable()) t.join();` (I'm leaning towards the one in the destructor) and change the other to just `t.join()`.

2. As you said, you can make `is_being_updated` atomic. That's a great solution.

Here's another solution. You can signal without holding the lock. (It's actually better form in general, as it helps reduce lock contention, since the first thing the woken thread needs to do is reacquire its mutex.)

```
void A::abort()
{
    {
        std::lock(m1, m2); // deadlock-proof
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lck(m1, std::adopt_lock);        
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> update_lock(m2, std::adopt_lock);        
        is_being_updated = false;
        this->value = 0; // Reset value
        aborted = true;
    }
    cv.notify_one(); // Signal abort ... 
    t.join(); // Wait for the thread to finish            
}
```

3. You're good. The way you wrote the wait, you will only come back if abort==true or 10 seconds has elapsed.

Answer (score 0):

1) I think this problem is inherent on your design, as it is a bool flag will not fix the problem. Maybe A shouldn't go out of scope until all the threads stop using it, in which case it should reside in a managed pointer like shared_ptr.

2) You should be using atomics for your bools and also value, this would avoid having to use the unique_lock for increasing the value and for returning it.

3) As I said in the comments the lambda in the cv handles the spurious wakeups.

Answer (score 0):

The biggest bit of code smell is using a full thread to update a variable every 10 seconds.  A heavy-weight OS thread with magabytes to gigabytes of address space to do one task every 10 seconds.

What more, it is updating a value without anyone being able to see the change.

You already have a `get_value` wrapping accessor.  Simply store the start point when you want to start counting.  When you call `get_value` calculate the time since the start point.  Divide by 10 seconds.  Use that to calculate the returned value.

In a real application, you'd have a timer system that lets you trigger events (either in a thread pool, or in a message pump) every period of time.  You'd use that instead of a dedicated thread to do something like this, and you'd make sure that modifying that value was vulgar (allowed people to subscribe to changes in it).  Then your abort would consist of deregistering the timer instead of stopping a thread.

Your system is a horrible mixture of the two, using threads for no good reason.

Comment: You need to understand that this is a purely hypothetical example that serves primarily as a learning experience to get a better feel of various threading constructs. Of course, it makes pretty much zero sense if you try to judge it as anything resembling real-world scenarios.

Comment: @w128 No, that is not clear.  It just looked like bad threading code that is quite commonly written.  My point is that this is practicing using threading primitives to do something that makes no sense.  Write a timer system, don't write a bespoke system to twiddle a value mixed in with other random business logic.  You wouldn't use `new` in the middle of business logic (at least you shouldn't!), neither should you create a thread.  Doing so isn't a "learning experience"; well, it is learning really bad habits in a pointlessly complex environment.

Comment: @w128 In short, your first problem is "you are messing with business logic in threading code", and you should throw out everything you wrote and keep threading code isolated with sensible primitives (C++ std primitives are good for writing sensible primitives, but are not themselves good primitives).  Every other question collapses under that fundamental problem; asking "should I use an atomic" is like saying "I'm playing russian roulette, what color scarf should I wear?"  All your other problems are *side effects*.